# List environment variables with C

Tags: c

I have used the below code to print the environmental variables.In that I have doubt is there a connection between the parameters of `char *argv[]` and `char *envp[]` in main function.

Sample Code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])    
{
  int index = 0;    
  while (envp[index])    
    printf("%s\n", envp[index++]);    
}
```

While executing the program after removed the arguments argc and argv I get segmentation fault.
Some one please explain this.!

Comment: "While executing the program after removed the arguments argc and argv I get segmentation fault. " - huh?  If you are having trouble with code then post the code you are having trouble with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what the arguments are called; only their position matters.

If you removed `argc` and `argv`, and so you only have

```
int main(char *envp[])
```

this is illegal (since the first argument should be an integer).

What is the problem with including `argc` and `argv`, but not using them?

Also, I should point out that `envp` is not portable. But it is accepted by the most widely used C implementations.

Answer (score 1):

main is called int main(int argc, char** argv, char** envp).

If you remove argc, argv, it will be

int main(char* envp[])

so envp will be set to argc, and there will be segmentation fault when envp[index++]